# PHP - Create image from other images

Tags: php, image, jquery-ui, imagemagick

I want to allow a user to drag some images into a div (using jquery ui draggable / droppable)

When they have positioned the images they can hit save and the content of that div (the images in their relevent positions) is saved as one large image.

Is this possible?

or would I need to store the positions of each element / image 9somehow) then "re-create" the positons that way?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store the location (x, y, z if that matters) using javascript, and then pass those values, as well as the images to your server-side php code, where you would use imagemagik to create the image.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible but may be unnecessary, as you say you could simply store the position of each `div` and reconstruct the composite image in HTML later. That would be simpler.

You tagged ImageMagick here but you wouldn't need it - the standard PHP GD functions would be perfectly adequate.

So you'd need something like:

- Javascript for dragging and dropping images
- AJAX to save the position of each (x, y and a z-index) to the server
- When viewing the image later, simply re-render the divs as they were saved